# ScrollHeight in Chrome

Tags: html, webkit

I am a novice in HTML and JavaScript. Now I have a strange question about ScrollHeight in Chrome.

I put an element `<a>` in a `<span>` in order to keep track of something. But I found that when I insert that `<a>` into or remove from a `<span>`, the `scrollHeight` property on `<body>` will change.

How can I do to fix that bug? It's ok in Firefox, so I felt sad that I don't understand the difference between webkit and gecko...

Answer (score 0):

I believe an `<a>` tag tells the browser that there is text in the mix and some browsers will then create empty space at the height of the default font size (whatever that is) which will alter your ScrollHeight.  This is just a guess. Whatever it is you're doing with this empty anchor, there's probably a better way to do it.  Why not describe what you're trying to achieve and ask for help on that front? :)